# Syntax for specializing function templates

Tags: c++, templates, swap

Is there a difference between the following approaches?

```
// approach 1
namespace std
{
    template<>
    void swap<Foo>(Foo& x, Foo& y)   // note the <Foo>
    {
        x.swap(y);
    }
}

// approach 2
namespace std
{
    template<>
    void swap(Foo& x, Foo& y)
    {
        x.swap(y);
    }
}
```

I stumpled upon this when I tried to specialize swap for my own string type and noticed that `swap<::string>` doesn't work, but for a completely different reason :)

Comment: And what type does `::string` name?

Comment: My own toy string type in the global namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is. But not in that particular example. If the parameter is not deduced, it can make a difference

```
template<typename T> void f(typename T::type t);
```

You cannot specialize that without `<type>` because it cannot deduce what `T` is from the parameter list.

```
struct MyType { typedef int type; };

// needs <MyType>
template<> void f<MyType>(int t) { }
```

Of course in your case, it's the digraph `<:` that's meaning the same as `[` causing your problem. Put a space like `<` `::string>` to avoid the problem.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation! And this digraph stuff is so funny :)

Comment: Do you know what actually leads to that syntax being allowed in the standard? I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: @gf you mean the `f<..>` syntax? It's a template-id, which is a id-expression, which is a declarator-id.

Comment: I mean the specialization syntax of `template<> R f(T)` instead of `template<> R f<T>(T)`.

Comment: @gf, See 14.8.1/2 and 14.7.3/11

Comment: Ah, i must have had a blind moment when i looked through *§14.7.3*. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you don't need to specialize in this case, just overload and be happy.

```
namespace std
{
    void swap(Foo& x, Foo& y)
    {
        x.swap(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you like undefined behavior, then yes :) You are not allowed to overload in the `std` namespace.